# How to pass value from one page to another page in the context of data binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, datacontext

I am creating an app where we have a Data Template list of building names and when clicked on say "Thomas Gosnell Hall", it will go to a new page with the TextBlock changed to that of the selected building name "Thomas Gosnell Hall". I know data binding is used to do this, but how do I do it across two different pages?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Tap="TextBlock_Tap" Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs** (When a user taps on the building name, it will navigate to new page)

```
    public void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        var building = ((TextBlock)sender).Text; // gets information based on the tapped building

        //perform action based on information about the tapped building 
        if(building == "Thomas Gosnell Hall")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("08 - (GOS)");
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MapLocation.xaml?building=" + building, UriKind.Relative)); // pass the string value to destination page through Uri parameter
        }
        else if(building == "Lyndon Baines Johnson Hall")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("060 - (LBJ)");
        }

    }
```

**MapLocation.xaml**

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="buildingName" Text="Building Name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

**MapLocation.xaml.cs** (The new page after the user selected the building name)

```
    /**
     * How to: Create the Binding (behind code)
     * Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1
     */
    // Define source object
    public class Building
    {
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    }

    public MapLocation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MapLocation_Loaded;

       /* // create an instance of the source object
        Building bldg = new Building();
        bldg.BuildingName = building; // value to change depending on user's click

        // create a binding object
        Binding MyBinding = new Binding();

        // set the binding properties on the binding object
        MyBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("BuildingName");
        MyBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;

        // set the source of the binding by setting the DataContext property
        buildingName.DataContext = bldg;

        // attach the binding to the property of the FrameworkElement
        buildingName.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, MyBinding);*/
    }

    private void MapLocation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        string building;
        if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("building", out building))
        {  
            //load information based on building parameter value
            buildingName.Text = building;
        }
    }

    /*public MapLocation_Loaded()
    {
        string building;
        if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("building", out building))
        {  
            //load information based on building parameter value
        }
    }*/
```

The problem lies within this line `bldg.BuildingName = building;` as it says `The name building does not exist in the current context.` It exists in the MainPage.xaml.cs, but not in MapLocation.xaml.cs. How do I data bind the building name depending on the user's tapped choice of building onto the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to pass the string value to destination page through `Uri` parameter :

```
public void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var building = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MapLocation.xaml?building=" + building, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Then handle loading correct informations in the destination page, for example in page `Loaded` event handler :

```
public MapLocation_Loaded()
{
    string building;
    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("building", out building))
    {  
        //load information based on building parameter value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But not quite getting the MapLocation class down. I updated my MapLocation.xaml.cs above. Is this the right format?

Comment: yep, that's look right. Did you pass the Uri parameter : `../MapLocation.xaml?building=..` ?

Comment: Yes I have from the MainPage! Sorry for asking so many questions, but I added this line of code in the `MapLocation_Loaded`'s if statement, `building = buildingName.Text;` the textblock still did not change. :/

Comment: is `buildingName` the name of textblock in MapLocation.xaml? If it so, try : `buildingName.Text = building;`

Comment: Finally got it, Thanks a bunch! So NavigationService is a good way of passing values from one page to the next.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to expose the selected value on MainPage as a public property. Then other pages can just read whatever value was set.

The other option is to pass it as state in the navigate method:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MapLocation.xaml", UriKind.Relative), building);
```

see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591042(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I changed the `TextBlock_Tap` property from a `private void` to a `public void`, but the `var building` is not being recognized by MapLocation class.

Comment: Not TextBlock_Tap.. thats a method, not a variable. You want to expose the users selection, which is in your sender control.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Where exactly do I put the public property to? I tried putting it in several places on the MainPage, but complains in your code that `sender` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry I misread where that was coming from. Just use the second method (navigate parameter)

Comment: I never thought of it that way, interesting! The Navigate parameter gives an error `No overload method 'Navigate' takes 2 arguments.` Am I missing something here?