# send an int id from one page to another universal windows app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I have to send the id that I get from a rest web service from page1.xaml to page2.xaml
I tried this code:

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
private async void Grid1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UriString2 = "URL";

            int x= rootObject.posts[0].id;
            string uri = string.Format("/Page2.xaml?x={1}",x);

            //adding Navigation Statement
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

Page2.xaml.cs:

```
 private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
            int xx = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationContext.QueryString["x"]);
        }
```

this code doesn't work,I have an error "NavigationContext doesn't exist in this context",miss I anything :(

thanks for help

Comment: I've seen a answer before, is this what you need? [How to pass value from one page to another page in the context of data binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464060/how-to-pass-value-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-the-context-of-data-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Navigation in UWP, you can use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(TargetPage));` method to navigate from current page to target page.

You can see my answer for another question:[Windows Phone 8.1 - Page Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154359/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation/23154444#23154444)

And in TargetPage, you can use `NavigationParameter` property to get navigation parameter.

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    var param = e.NavigationParameter;
}
```

And in you case, code should be:

SourcePage:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), rootObject.posts[0].id);
```

TargetPage:

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    string idStr = e.NavigationParameter as string;
    int id = int.Parse(idStr);
}
```

Comment: thanks Chris for your reply but I have an error <<The type or namespace LoadStateEventArgs could not be found >> :/

Comment: I didn't foun any Basic Page when I try to create a new item in my project,I work on a windows 10 project

Comment: OK. If LoadState event can't be used. You can use OnNavigatedTo event.

Comment: thanks Sir it works now with the OnNavigatedTo method :)